# Update NativeScript plugin nativescript-local-notifications to support images

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to update the NativeScript plugin [`nativescript-local-notifications`](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications) to display images in the notifications.

That's already working on Android [here](https://github.com/Danziger/nativescript-local-notifications/pull/1), but I'm having some issues when trying to implement the same thing for iOS.

I have done some changes to the method `schedulePendingNotificationsNew` in [`local-notifications.ios.ts`](https://github.com/Danziger/nativescript-local-notifications/pull/1/files#diff-12fd1196b0d9e83f7a36a20ed13e9078):

```
private static async schedulePendingNotificationsNew(pending: ScheduleOptions[]): Promise<void> {

    ...

    content.userInfo = userInfoDict; // Not changed

    if (options.image) {            
        const image: ImageSource = await imageSource.fromUrl(options.image);
        const imageName: string = options.image.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
        const imageExtension: "png" | "jpeg" | "jpg" = <"png" | "jpeg" | "jpg">imageName.split('.')[1]
        const folderDest = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.temp();
        const pathDest = fileSystemModule.path.join(folderDest.path, imageName);

        console.log(`Image will be saved to = ${ pathDest }`);

        const saved = image.saveToFile(pathDest, imageExtension);

        console.log(`Image ${ saved ? '' : 'not' } saved. `);
        console.log(`Image does ${ fileSystemModule.File.exists(pathDest) ? '' : 'not' } exist. `);

        if (saved || fileSystemModule.File.exists(pathDest)) {
            console.log('Attaching image...');

            try {
                const attachment = UNNotificationAttachment
                .attachmentWithIdentifierURLOptionsError('attachment', NSURL.fileURLWithPath('file://' + pathDest), null);
                // .attachmentWithIdentifierURLOptionsError('attachment', NSURL.fileURLWithPath(pathDest), null);

                content.attachments = NSArray.arrayWithObject<UNNotificationAttachment>(attachement);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log('Attachment error ; ', err);
            }

            console.log('Image attached!');
        }
    }

    const repeats = options.interval !== undefined; // Not changed

    ...
}
```

You can see I have created the attachment in two different ways:

```
const attachment = UNNotificationAttachment
    .attachmentWithIdentifierURLOptionsError('attachment', 
        NSURL.fileURLWithPath('file://' + pathDest), null);
```

And:

```
const attachment = UNNotificationAttachment
    .attachmentWithIdentifierURLOptionsError('attachment',
        NSURL.fileURLWithPath(pathDest), null);
```

But none of them work, in both cases I get a text-only notification and these logs:

```
Image will be saved to = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Library/Caches/1974-lancia-stratos-hf-stradale-for-sale.jpg
Image not saved.
Image does not exist.
```

I'm testing it on an iPhone 7 and an iPhone 8 and the image I'm trying to save is this one: https://icdn-0.motor1.com/images/mgl/7WjgW/s3/1974-lancia-stratos-hf-stradale-for-sale.jpg

Comment: @rmaddy This code is compiled to native code, so someone who knows how to implement this properly in Swift or Objective-C might be able to help as well, as the solution might be simply searching for the equivalent classes and methods in NS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by forcing the image to be saved as `png`:

```
export class LocalNotificationsImpl extends LocalNotificationsCommon implements LocalNotificationsApi {

    ...

    private static guid() {
        // Not the best, but will it will do. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

        const s4 = () => Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);

        return `${ s4() }${ s4() }-${ s4() }-${ s4() }-${ s4() }-${ s4() }${ s4() }${ s4() }`;
    }

    private static getImageName(imageURL: string = "", extension: "png" | "jpeg" | "jpg" = "png"): [string, string] {
        const name: string = imageURL.split(/[\/\.]/).slice(-2, -1)[0] || LocalNotificationsImpl.guid();

        return [name, `${ name }.${ extension }`];
    }

    ...

    private static async schedulePendingNotificationsNew(pending: ScheduleOptions[]): Promise<void> {

        ...

        const imageURL: string = options.image;

        if (imageURL) {
            const image: ImageSource = await imageSource.fromUrl(imageURL);
            const [imageName, imageNameWithExtension] = LocalNotificationsImpl.getImageName(imageURL, "png");
            const path: string = fileSystemModule.path.join(
                fileSystemModule.knownFolders.temp().path,
                LocalNotificationsImpl.getImageName(imageURL, "png"),
            );

            const saved = image.saveToFile(path, "png");

            if (saved || fileSystemModule.File.exists(path)) {                
                try {
                    const attachment = UNNotificationAttachment
                        .attachmentWithIdentifierURLOptionsError('attachment', NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path), null);

                    content.attachments = NSArray.arrayWithObject<UNNotificationAttachment>(attachment);
                } catch(err) {}
            }
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

If you are interested, these changes have been merged to [my fork of the plugin](https://github.com/Danziger/nativescript-local-notifications) and there's a [PR open in the official one](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications/pull/103).